# Como colocar o Qt 5.7 com MSVC2015 para funcionar?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015

Tenho o Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 faz tempo.

Instalei o Qt 5.7 via instalador online e inclui msvc2015 (já estava marcado) na lista de programas da instalação. Tentei usar o Qt Creator, mas ele dá um erro de compilação.

A mensagem de compilação é a seguinte.

```
10:48:14: Running steps for project BinaryConverter...
10:48:14: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
10:48:15: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\BinaryConverter.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\BinaryConverter -I. -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\RHERWOLF\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.3708.47.jom
'cl' nÆo ‚ reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
jom: E:\Dropbox\Projetos\Qt Creator Projects\build-BinaryConverter-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 1
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\BinaryConverter.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\BinaryConverter -I. -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\RHERWOLF\AppData\Local\Temp\unwin.obj.3708.546.jom
'cl' nÆo ‚ reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
jom: E:\Dropbox\Projetos\Qt Creator Projects\build-BinaryConverter-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\unwin.obj] Error 1
jom: E:\Dropbox\Projetos\Qt Creator Projects\build-BinaryConverter-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
10:48:19: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project BinaryConverter (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
10:48:19: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Depois baixei do site e instalei "Qt VS Tools MSVC 2015". Apareceu no Visual Studio a opção de criar projeto GUI do Qt...

[image: Criação do projeto do Qt no VS.]

...mas ao tentar criar um projeto ocorre o erro abaixo.

[image: Erro que aparece ao confirmar a criação do projeto.]

O que eu faço para finalmente usar o Qt?

Answer (score 2):

O seu erro com o QtCreator provavelmente é alguma configuração errada mesmo (conforme indica a mensagem de erro). Se for usá-lo, sugiro tentar recriar o Kit do VS 2015 ([siga a documentação do Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html)).

Sobre o VS Toolkit, eu não sei como ajudar. Nunca gostei dessa ferramenta porque ela é difícil de entender e usar e quase sempre dá algum problema. Fora que tem dificuldades sérias de atualização entre as versões do Visual Studio. [Esse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBHkeCVMJqM) pode ser útil (não sei se está atualizado) e talvez outro colega que trabalhe com o Qt (o @GuilhermeNascimento muito provavelmente! rs) possa te ajudar com isso.

Mas é possível gerar os arquivos do Visual Studio diretamente a partir do arquivo de projeto (arquivo .pro) usando o [qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html#creating-visual-studio-project-files). E a vantagem de usar o qmake é que você ganha portabilidade: pode gerar os arquivos de projeto do VS no Windows ou os arquivos do Make (makefiles) no Linux, por exemplo.

Eu costumava usar esse script (com extensão .cmd) que funcionava tanto no Windows (como script batch) como no Linux (como script bash):

```
:;#
:;# This is a combined Batch (Windows) + Bash (Linux) command file that:
:;# - (re)creates the Visual Studio project files (if ran on Windows)
:;# - (re)creates the project Makefile (if ran on Linux)
:;#
:;# The syntax used to create the combined Batch-Bash commands comes from this
:;# answer in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623721/2896619
:;#
:;# The .cmd extension was used just to make it less weird when used on Linux! :)
:;#
:;# Author: Luiz C. Vieira
:;# Version: 1.0
:;#

:; qmake -o Makefile core.pro; exit
@echo off
qmake -spec win32-msvc2012 -tp vc
```

Ele usa um "truque" bacana (descrito [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623721/2896619)) para poder executar tanto no Windows como no Linux.

Mas nos últimos anos eu troquei tudo isso pelo uso do [CMake](https://cmake.org/). Além de ser uma ferramenta livre fantástica, facilita muitíssimo trabalhar quando se deseja portabilidade, e muitos dos projetos *open source* por aí a utilizam (o que também facilita a integração quando esses projetos são utilizados). Ela tem uma pequena curva de aprendizado, claro, mas vale muitíssimo a pena o tempo gasto. Com o CMake eu não preciso sequer me preocupar com os diretórios onde as dependências se encontram, e ele é capaz de gerar e manter os arquivos de projeto do Visual Studio 2015 (e você *nunca mais* precisará esquentar a cabeça com o VS Toolkit!).

Eis um exemplo de arquivo `CMakeLists.txt` (que fica na raiz do seu projeto, e que contém sua configuração para o CMake):

```
# Versão mínima do CMake esperada
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

# Nome do projeto
project(teste)

# Define as configurações de compilação disponíveis no projeto (debug, release, etc)
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release"
    "MinSizeRel" "RelWithDebInfo")
endif()

# Configuração do Qt5
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) # Automaticamente faz o MOC das classes QObject
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON) # Automaticamente compila os arquivos de recurso
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) # Automaticamente gera os metadados das interfaces gráficas
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Core Gui Widgets) # Encontra o Qt e adiciona os pacotes desejados

# Configura o código-fonte do seu projeto
# (nesse caso, se encontra na subpasta `./src/`)
file(GLOB SRC src/*.cpp src/*.h)

# Cria o projeto do executável, apontando para o código-fonte
# No Windows usa `WIN32` para indicar que é uma aplicação gráfica
# (caso contrário, seria somente uma aplicação "console")
if(WIN32)
    add_executable(teste WIN32 ${SRC})
else()
    add_executable(teste ${SRC})
endif()

# Linka o projeto com as bibliotecas do Qt
target_link_libraries(teste Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)

# No caso do Qt os includes são feitos automaticamente pelo `find_package`,
# mas em outras bibliotecas você pode precisar incluir também algo do tipo:
#
# `include_directories(${VAR})`
#
# onde VAR é uma variável com todos os paths de includes.
#
# As bibliotecas costumam indicar em sua documentação o nome da variável que
# fornecem justamente para esse propósito. Por exemplo, ao se usar OpenCV:
#
# `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui imgproc)`
# `include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})`
#
```

Para usá-lo, basta abrir o CMake, definir o diretório do projeto (onde está o `CMakeLists.txt`) e o de "build" (onde o projeto do VS vai ser gerado, e onde os arquivos compilados vão ser produzidos quando vc trabalhar dentro do VS; esse pode ser qualquer path, e vc pode apagá-lo e gerar de novo se precisar - por isso é bom manter separado).

No meu exemplo eu tenho a seguinte estrutura na raiz do projeto:

```
c:\temp\SOPT\
    .\CMakeLists.txt
    .\src\main.cpp
```

E, por comodidade, gerei os binários em:

```
c:\temp\SOPT\build\
    .\teste.sln
    .\teste.vcxproj
    etc
```

(Lembrando que a pasta `c:\temp\SOPT\build\` é gerada, e pode ser apagada sem problema porque não contém os fontes).

Após abrir o CMake eu defini os diretórios e cliquei em "Configure". Ele vai (1) perguntar se cria o diretório de build e (2) pedir pra selecionar o compilador. O Visual Studio 2015 tem a versão "14" (por causa das idiossincrasias da Microsoft). Lembre-se também de escolher a versão entre 32 ou 64 bits dependendo da sua instalação do Qt. Após confirmar ele vai ler a configuração e preparar o projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Não se assuste com a cor vermelha. Ela não indica erro. Apenas que as variáveis foram encontradas. O Cmake permite alterar as variáveis via essa interface, o que muitas vezes é útil).

Agora é só clicar em "Generate" que o projeto vai ser gerado (ou atualizado, se você fez alguma mudança em um projeto já gerado). O botão "Open Project" abre o VS sozinho pra vc, mas você encontra o arquivo da solução (`teste.sln`, no meu exemplo) na pasta de build que você usou.

Aí, é só abrir o Visual Studio, compilar e ser feliz! :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *window = new QLabel();

    window->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    window->setStyleSheet("QLabel { font: 50px; background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1, stop: 0.2 #ffcece, stop: 1.0 #ceffce); }");
    window->setWordWrap(true);

    window->setFixedSize(700, 400);
    window->setWindowTitle("Olá Mundo!");

    window->setText("Bem vindo ao teste de Qt 5 com Visual Studio 2015 para o Stack Overflow em Português!");

    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado por me citar, realmente Qt+MSVC é algo complicado, mas pelo erro tenho quase certeza ser a falta do vsaddin correto, ele pode ter instalado o 1.2.5 ou pode ter instalado a versão 2.0.0 para o VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que apenas faltou baixar o:

http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-tools-msvc2015-2.0.0.vsix

É que está muito no final da página e as vezes passa despercebido: https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-10

Note que existem 2:

[image: downloads]

No seu caso especifico é o ultimo, a versão *1.2.5* só funciona para o VS2013 e se instalou o *VS-Add-in 2.0.0 for Qt5 MSVC 2013* não vai funcionar mesmo.

Eu tive dificuldade de instalar pois até a alguns meses o *VS-Add-in 2.0.0 for Qt5 MSVC 2015* era *beta* e não estava disponível na página, tive que baixar do repositório, mas creio estar estável.

Comment: Pois é. Justamente por essas dificuldades que eu desisti de usar faz tempo. :)

Comment: Na verdade eu até demorei pra reparar nele, mas já tinha instalado e testado com ele quando postei. Portanto o problema é outro.

Comment: @RHERWOLF certeza que instalou o correto? Tentou desinstalar e instalar novamente?